# 'InvalidClientTokenId' error while initialising AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to initialise amplify by doing

```
$ amplify init
```

in an Android project. Somehow, every time the setup is failing with the following stacktrace:

> ⠹ Initializing project in the cloud...An error occurred when creating
>   the CloudFormation stack ✖ Root stack creation failed init failed {
>   InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is
>   invalid.
>       at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
>       at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:109:20)
>       at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:81:10)
>       at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
>       at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
>       at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
>       at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:119:18)
>   message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
>   code: 'InvalidClientTokenId',   time: 2018-10-30T12:24:49.192Z,
>   requestId: 'cb4cc85a-dc3e-11e8-ad2e-1dd03551193d',   statusCode: 403, 
>   retryable: false,   retryDelay: 71.00058281764416 } An error occurred
>   when  creating the CloudFormation stack

I tried deleting credentials and config files in ~/.aws/ folder along with deleting the AWS IAM user and running

```
$ aws configure
```

again followed by the init command but nothing helped. Don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem in a weird way. May be it helps someone else. It turns out that I am able to get rid of the error after reinstalling amplify cli:

```
$ sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I needed to finish setting up my AWS account and add credit card info and finish the setup process on the AWS website.